# Link variables in numerical Chern number calculation

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

A well known method to calculate the Chern number numerically is the one proposed by Fukui et al. (http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503172).

Here they make use of 'U(1) Link variables' to obtain a gauge invariant lattice field strength from which the first Chern number may be obtained. However, I do not see how the lattice field strength in Eq. 8 reduces to the continuum field strength in Eq. 5 upon taking $\delta k \to 0$.

Wang et al. (http://link.springer.com/10.1007/s12200-019-0963-9) argue that the link variable is the normalization of $\exp{A_\mu \delta k_\mu}$ in Eq. 16 of their work.

But if this is the case, I do not see why the link variables should be normalized as substituting $U = \exp{A_\mu \delta k_\mu}$ (instead of the normalized version) into Eq. 8 of Fukui et al. results in the continuum field strength.